# How to create 'Local' filters for WordPress srcset sizes in template parts?

Tags: images, filters, templates, responsive

I've read a bunch of tutorials on how to create filters for `srcsets` and `srcset` sizes, but they all appear to be applied globally, with a fixed width or set of widths for sizes.

The trouble is, I pull in content from posts and pages in template parts throughout my sites, and these typically display the featured image in a much smaller context.

So although it's properly using Wordpress's responsive images, the width by default is set to `100vw`, so even if it's never displayed at larger than 1/3rd of the screen width, it'll still be loading a `srcset` intended for full-width screens.

How can I create individual filters (or any other appropriate method), for each template part so I can control more precisely the sizes in my `srcsets`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are trying to describe, but I do know that templates aren't _sandboxed_ in any way, there's no state to tell code which template its currently in if you `get_template_part` to call upon

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply, sorry it took me so long to respond.

I'll try and explain a little better.

Everything I've read has fixes adjusting the srcset and srcset sizes globally.

What I want to be able to do is to create a filter(?) within a template part to be able to specify the sizes attribute for that template part, because I know that the images in that template part will never be more than X wide.